# jQuery fadeIn/Out stuttering with rounded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a circular div that contains an image. On hover of that image I'd like the opacity to change to black and display an overlapping div containing some information. So far I'm able to do the hover successfully but when a users mouse crosses the 200px x 200px div boundary, the fadeIn fires - which isn't a bad thing. When the user then moves their mouse within the circle, it fires again. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="prodava" onmouseover="jQuery('#fader-123').fadeIn('fast');" onmouseout="jQuery('#fader-123').fadeOut('fast');">                     
    <a href="www.google.com/asd" class="product_item_link">
        <img src="theimage.jpg" />
        <div id="fader-123" class="prodavahl" style="display: none;">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.prodava {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 1px;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin:10px;
}

.prodava img {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 101px; /* must be width + border */
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}

.prodavahl {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 101px; /* must be width + border */
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
}

.prodavahl span {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/EbUGujE/6/edit)

```
<div class="prodava">                     
    <a href="www.google.com/asd" class="product_item_link">
        <img src="theimage.jpg" />
        <div id="fader-123" class="prodavahl" style="display: none;">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('.prodava').hover(function( e ){
      $(this).find('.prodavahl').stop()[e.type=='mouseenter'?'fadeIn':'fadeOut'](200);
    });

});
```

The code above does exactly the same as:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('.prodava').mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).find('.prodavahl').stop().fadeIn(200);
    }, mouseleave(function(){
      $(this).find('.prodavahl').stop().fadeOut(200);
    });

});
```

which is than simplified into

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    $('.prodava').hover(function( e ){
      if(e.type=='mouseenter'){
          $(this).find('.prodavahl').stop().fadeIn(200);
      }else{
          $(this).find('.prodavahl').stop().fadeOut(200);
      }
    });

});
```

and than minified into the very top example with the use of a Ternary Operator `(?:)`

Comment: Sounds great but the product Id's are database generated, random and upredictable. This solution would work in this particular example but not so much for multiple divs with the same class name. Had a play but couldn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events or their shortcut [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

From mouseenter Doc

> The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles
>   event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the
>   mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse enters the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

```
<div class="prodava"> <a href="www.google.com/asd" class="product_item_link">
        <img src="theimage.jpg" />
        <div id="fader-123" class="prodavahl" style="display: none;">
            <span>Hello</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prodava').hover(function () {
        jQuery('#fader-123').finish().fadeIn('fast');
    }, function () {
        jQuery('#fader-123').finish().fadeOut('fast');
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8w2Qd/)

Comment: `.finish()` is a bad solution. `.stop()` method is in this cases always smoother and much more gentle for a better UX